# How to get Materia from Aeris' hair in the Forgotten Capital?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

What kind of Materia is falling from Aeris' hair while in the Forgotten Capital?

Is it possible to catch that materia? How?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is the White Materia, used for Holy, the most powerful White magic in the game.

It plays an important role in the plot so the plot summary is in the spoiler below. If you want more spoilers, the plot related to it can be hound here on the [FF wiki](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/White_Materia)

> The White Materia is used to summon Holy. This is the only power capable of stopping Meteor, which was summoned by Sephiroth using the Black Materia. Aerith goes to the Forgotten Capital to pray to Holy, but is killed by Sephiroth. It turns out that she did successfully summon Holy, but Sephiroth is preventing it taking effect. You kill Sephiroth, Holy emerges, but Meteor is too close to be stopped by Holy alone. The Lifestream is used to push Meteor back, allowing Holy to destroy it.

Comment: Wow. I don't remember that much detail in the plot of FFVII. Either I didn't notice it (quite possible), it got lost in translation or it wasn't in the original game. Maybe I should play it again.

Comment: Ehi, thank you! Great resources following that link.

Comment: @Greg the information is definitly there, but its very 'in between the lines' in some places. multiple playthroughs are definitly recommended to understand the entire story.

Answer (score 2):

It is the White Materia.  If you recall, when you first met Aeris, she said that she had a materia that was good for absolutely nothing (ironic, eh?).  This is that materia and no, there is no way to get it for yourself.  Though it does come back into the game later on in a way (and you still don't get to have it then, but that is okay).

Answer (score -5):

Actually you can get Holy materia. I did it like 20 years ago. It is a long complicated process to get though and you can only get it on disc 2.

The first step is to kill Emerald Weapon, and Ruby Weapon, and finish qualm traveler quest. Once you have given the Earth Harp up the hard part comes into effect. Yes, the weapons are not the hardest part. The next step is at Gold saucer. You have to win Speed Square 57 times. Then a guy outside Speed Square announces the prizes were changed. You then need to get 5000 to get the Masamune blade, the sword, not the item. Once you have this you go to battle square and win the battle. You need to have throw materia. The boss needs to be morphed into another Earth harp by throwing the Masamune blade at it when low health. If successful the boss will turn into another Earth Harp. Now that the hard part is done, head back to ancient city area but stay the night. Should get a vision. The next day head to where Aeris died and guess what? Use the Earth Harp and Mr. Fish goes bye bye. Now you can walk down and get Holy.

I know this works on PlayStation. I just recently started playing again on Steam. I'm not sure if PlayStation and PC are different. I had a guide to this long time ago, but have not been able to find it again.